# Как сделать ещё одну модель, в которой будут храниться диалоги?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель с сообщениями, id отправителя и id получателя. Как сделать ещё одну модель, в которой будут храниться диалоги?

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,) 
    msg_content = models.TextField(null='True')
```

Как сделать модель, которая будет выводить диалоги с переписками пользователей?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Message(models.Model):
  sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
  reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,) 
  msg_content = models.TextField(null='True')
  dialog = models.ForeignKey(Dialog)


class Dialog(models.Model):
    uchastnik = models.ManyToMany(User)
    title = models.TextField()
```

Comment: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_message.dialog_id ошибка из формы html

Comment: products = Message(msg_content=formaget, sender=request.user, reciever=userse , dialog=я не знаю какое значение тут поставить )

Comment: я вам просто идею подсказал. вашу реализацию я не видел, и ошибки ваши мне не о чем не говорят.

Comment: Возможно, следует null=True добавить?

Comment: если у вас могут быть сообщения  без диалога то да следует null=True, если нет то нет. Логику вам выбирать